Play Store privacy url is invalid in Facebook app review
We use Facebook login for our app, which was approved by Facebook for iOS, Android, and web.  All of a sudden, they say the privacy url in the Play Store (which was approved by Google) is invalid and leads to a page not found error.  It is the same url used in the Apple app store, and accessible from within the apps; it is also the URL that we have in our Facebook developer console, without any issues.  The problem is only with Android somehow.
That url is from a WordPress website:
https://www.waterfallroutes.com/terms
So we created a new, static privacy page, thinking Facebook was somehow having trouble with the WP code, and that worked for a month... and then all of a sudden rejected because of the same page not found error.
https://www.waterfallroutes.com/privacy.html
Wondering if there was still some sort of interference from WordPress, we created a new subdomain with a static html page, but that was rejected for the same reason!
https://privacy.waterfallroutes.com
Can anyone suggest how to create a privacy page that Facebook can successfully access via our Play Store page?  It is not a content issue, they literally can't seem to open the website page.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.waterfallroutes.waterfall
We are out of ideas, and the Facebook reviewers refuse to provide any detail or context, much less accept that there is some issue with their testing system, even though the iOS and web apps are without any issues.

Those are your terms and conditions. Privacy policies are a different thing and look more like this: https://stackoverflow.com/legal/privacy-policy

We have them all together.  And the issue isn't that they reject the text (which is otherwise accepted), the issue is that they can't open the page from the Google Play Store.  That's why I posted here, it's some sort of technical issue, not content-related.

I've edited to make it clearer that the issue is that they can't open the website page, not a content issue.

The solution was to create a simple, static page and then host it on a completely new website.  Whatever the system is that Meta uses to review Android apps breaks with WordPress; then once something is broken, it can't seem to handle that domain anymore.  Perhaps that is a cache issue on their part?  Who knows, it was maddening.

And now two days later, they have decided to reject it again.  Not sure what to do.
